# Windows 10 does not (or only partially) search Dropbox

Tags: windows-10, search, dropbox, search-indexing

I'm a Dropbox user on Windows 10, with automatic updates enabled.
I've got some portable software installed in a folder in my Dropbox. 
When I hit my Windows key and start typing, for example "winscp.exe" (a portable program in my dropbox), no results come up. If I click on "search", just below my keyword, after a while only an .ini file with a mention of WinSCP pops up.

I've tried:

1. Right clicking my dropbox folder, disabling indexing, saving, re-enabling indexing and saving again.
2. Rebuilding the index.
3. Specifically choosing Dropbox as a folder to be indexed in my index settings.

Please note my Dropbox folder is installed on a separate hard drive E:. I've got the impression that searches on the C:\ drive do produce better results.

What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried disabling other unnecessary location to be indexed. I have seen that sometimes it wants to index in the Millions of items. I have disabled the indexing of all other users not being logged into on my PC . I only have it indexing my start menu for my apps and my own logged in user (c:/users/****your user***).

This seems to help a lot to make the search responsive.

Right-click start button -> Control Panel -> Indexing Options -> Modify
Choose only the folders as suggested above